# Inverse of multivariate normal under restrictions on marginal CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is it possible to uniquely define an inverse of a multivariate normal distribution by applying some further restrictions on the values of the CDFs of the marginals? For example, if we insist that the marginal CDFs have to be the same, i.e. $\Phi_1(x_1;\mu_1,\sigma_1) = \Phi_2(x_2;\mu_2,\sigma_2) = ... = \Phi_n(x_n;\mu_n,\sigma_n)$. Is this conditions enough to uniquely define $\Phi^{-1}_{x_1,x_2,...x_n}(p)$? What about a restriction on the combination of marginal CDFs, e.g. minimize $\sum\Phi_i(x_i)$ or $\sum(\Phi_i(x_i))^2$? Are there some general conditions on the restrictions that have to be imposed to guarantee a unique inverse?

If a CDF is defined not using rectangular regions, but using ellipsoids, then - 
if my understanding is correct - for a 2d case of bivariate normal, the inverse of the CDF at $p$ defines an ellipse given by

$$ -2\ln(1-p) = (\mathbf x -\mathbf \mu)^T \mathbf \Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mathbf \mu)$$

and the condition $\Phi_1(x_1;\mu_1,\sigma_1) = \Phi_2(x_2;\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ defines a straight line by

$$\mathbf x = \mathbf\mu + \Phi^{-1}_{0,1}(\alpha) \mathbf \sigma  : \alpha \in (0,1)$$

where $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2)^T$, $\mathbf\mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2)^T$, and $\mathbf \sigma = (\sigma_1,\sigma_2)^T$. Substituting and solving for $\Phi^{-1}_{0,1}(\alpha)$ gives

$$ \Phi^{-1}_{0,1}(\alpha) = \pm \sqrt \frac{-2\ln(1-p)}{\mathbf\sigma^T \mathbf\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf\sigma} $$

Thus, the intersection of the ellipse and the straight line  would give two pairs of points, and one would then take the point falling into the lower left quadrant (relative to the mean $\mathbf \mu$) by taking the negative of the square root above.